# During leaving body, does chanting and remembering eternal one help?

Tags: death

During leaving body, does chanting and remembering eternal one/parmatma affect next life?

If yes, how? What's logic behind it? Are there references?

Comment: When one remembers Paramatma during time of leaving body, he attains Moksha and is not reborn. Krishna assures in Gita that those who think of him at time of death attains him.

Answer (score 2):

This should be chanted your whole life. This is how you build up an agregate of samsaras or impressions that create your consciosuness and, based on your consciousness, your destiny in this life and next. If the gravity of your consciousness is more spiritual, you will be remembering your spiritual life and end up in your desired spiritual destination.

Take for example the [story of Ajāmila](http://causelessmercy.com/?P=SB6#1). He was a good brahmana and engaged in spiritual life. Unfortunately, he fell in love with one prostitute and became a materialisitc man. He had one son, by the name Narayan, and he called his name every day. In this way he chanted the name Narayan every day and living in rememberance of Narayana. At the end of his life, Jamadutas approcahed him to for the sins he did in his life. But he died while uttering the name Narayana and this qualified him to go in spiritual destinations.